# How can I execute the uv smart project operator per polygon or face of a mesh in python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, faces

The last state of my unsuccessful attempts has been the attached code sample.

```
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
for face in bm.faces:
    face.select_set(True)
    if bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll():
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project()
    face.select_set(False)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

This will lead to an error "ReferenceError: BMesh data of type BMFace has been removed". Replacing

```
face.select_set(False)
```

by

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
```

leads to a Blender crash.

Comment: The last line `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)` is indented and thus repeatedly executed in the for loop. I don't think this is intended and might cause the error.